# Browser cannot get woff font file using @font-face

Tags: html, css, font-face, woff, woff2

For my server I wish to enable dynamic loading of fonts. The server runs with nestjs

I host the .woff files in a directory on the server named 'fonts'.

The @font-face is constructed dynamically (according to desired fonts) in a style tag in the html's head section.

However, when I set the url to the file's path, like this:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: Roboto;
      src: url(fonts/roboto-v29-latin-regular.woff);
    }
```

then the GET ends with 404 not found.

When I simply use the file's name:

```
@font-face {
          font-family: Roboto;
          src: url(roboto-v29-latin-regular.woff);
        }
```

then an empty object is returned {}

Would appreciate your insights!

Comment: _"then an empty object is returned {}"_ - what do you mean by that? Who returns what to where here?

Comment: Are you trying to use the roboto google-font but hosting the font files yourself?

Comment: @CBroe my server returns an empty json to the browser

Comment: @FabianS. yes, to test the created font-face scopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions that could be potential fixes, depends on how you handle your CSS files.

If you have the `roboto-v29-latin-regular.woff` file inside `fonts` folder, it means that CSS tries to find the path in the local directory. To find something in the local directory use dot in front of the slash ( `./` ). So if we have the following directory:

```
/fonts
 -roboto-v29-latin-regular.woff
styles.css
```

Then the path for `roboto-v29-latin-regular.woff` would be `./fonts/roboto-v29-latin-regular.woff` and it would result in the following font-face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  src: url(./fonts/roboto-v29-latin-regular.woff);
}
```

This is how you can easily access local or directories above the current level you are on. Read [this](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejac22/books/www/book/node82.html).

However if you process CSS differently, you have to provide only one `/` in front of the `fonts` folder which would result from font fetching from the local instance server URL:

```
/* Imagine your URL to be: http://localhost:3000/fonts/roboto-v29-latin-regular.woff */

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  src: url(/fonts/roboto-v29-latin-regular.woff);
}
```

Again if none of the solutions above work just place the font external URL ( from google fonts etc. )

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  src: url(<EXTERNAL_URL>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that nestjs did not serve the font files.
I had to serve them statically from the appModule using ServeStaticModule.forRoot:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'fonts'),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

then copy my fonts folder to the dist directory.
This fixed the problem.